# Dynamics CRM 2013 Import option-set mapping with multiple values

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, data-import

I have a column in an import file that should be linked to an option set in CRM. There are values like “All” like in this case below for example:

[image]

Can we support these type of scenarios somehow when importing data to CRM?

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optionsets inside Dynamics CRM can hold maximum one value, they don't hold multiple choices, so in your case a Category can be only an Hotel or an Office, can't be both Hotel and Office (or all your values)